# Run ltrace to avoid detection (on a different PID?)

Tags: debugging, buffer-overflow

I am trying to run `ltrace` on this file:

> ./launcher: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=f6f8cf3307e0ee26723f4d03ec68f022d15e56b6, stripped

When I pop it open in ghidra, and view the decompiled c, I can see that it changes the program flow to somewhere I don't want to be when ltrace is running.

```
  attached_to_ptrace = ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,1,0);
  if (attached_to_ptrace == -1) {
    puts("I am not your property!");
    exit_code = 1;
  }
  else {
    // execute main loop
  }
```

Looking at the man page for `ptrace`, I see:

```
long ptrace(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid,
                   void *addr, void *data);
```

Meaning that if the program? or ltrace? were to run with a different PID, I would be able to successfully run my program using ltrace.

This is the current output I get when running the program with `ltrace`:

```
~/ctf/cyberstart/level13/04 [master|…1] $ ltrace ./launcher
__libc_start_main(0x565a86f0, 1, 0xff837be4, 0x565a8970 <unfinished ...>
ptrace(0, 0, 1, 0)                                                     = 0xffffffff
puts("I am not your property!"I am not your property!
)                                        = 24
+++ exited (status 1) +++
```

Without ltrace:

```
~/ctf/cyberstart/level13/04 [master|…1] $ ./launcher

Enter the password:
password
Away now, you anklebiter!

[1]+  Stopped                 ./launcher
```

(This is my second buffer overflow CTF challenge, where the main goal is to mess with this block of code:)

```
  int iVar1;
  char local_1e [10];
  int local_14;
  int local_10;
  
  local_10 = 0;
  puts("\nEnter the password: ");
  gets(local_1e);
  iVar1 = strcmp(local_1e,"PAssw0rd");
  if (iVar1 == 0) {
    puts("Well done! Unfortunately, you have to try harder.");
    local_10 = 0;
  }
  else {
    puts("Away now, you anklebiter!");
  }
  if (local_10 != 0) {
    printf("Unexpected error condition. Control char is %d\n",local_10);
    local_14 = param_2 * local_10;
    (*(code *)(local_14 + param_1))();
  }
```

**How can I run ltrace in a way such that it isn't detected?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ghidra method

You can modify the binary via Ghidra in the following way:

- load the track
- move in the assembly code to the point where it checks the result (if statement)
- you will probably be faced with a jump instruction `JNZ`, just right click on it and select "Patch Instruction" and replace it with the opposite condition `JZ` (or vice versa).
- Now save the project (`Ctrl`+`S`)
- Then navigate to `File`>`Export` Program and decide where to save the modified binary

If you have problems with the exported binary, try this script: https://github.com/schlafwandler/ghidra_SavePatch

#### LD_PRELOAD method

- Create a file called `ptrace.c` with the following content:

```
long ptrace(int request, int pid, void *addr, void *data) {
    return 0;
}
```

- Now build the file as a shared library: `gcc -shared ptrace.c -o ptrace.so`;
- Now lunch the following command: `export LD_PRELOAD=./ptrace.so`
- Run `ltrace ./launcher`

> Note: you can also use LD_PRELOAD method with GDB

## GDB method

- use GDB to lunch the binary: `gdb ./launcher`
- in the GDB client shell: `catch syscall ptrace`
- GDB allows you tun run a series of command when you reach a BP: `command 1`
- type: `set ($rax) = 0`, that will change the value inside the "return" register (aka the result of ptrace syscall) [x86-registers](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2017/fall/cs301/lecture/09_11_registers.html)
- then enter: `continue` and `end`
  (as two separated commands)
- place a BP on the main function: `b main` and then type `r` to continue the execution

Another option is to use Qiling framework and hook the function/syscall and always return any other value than "-1", but that seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the CALL to ptrace with NOPs or use LD_PRELOAD to inject your own fake ptrace code which does nothing but return a value other than -1.